# What will be trajectory of a free falling rotating fan?

Tags: rotational-kinematics, free-fall, coriolis-effect

Consider a situation, where a fan  is rotating in full swing. Suddenly, the contact between ceiling  and fan bearing is broken. What will be trajectory  of fan if it falls under the infulence of gravity?

Comment: is it in perfect balance?

Comment: This is a simplified version of an autorotation engine-out landing of a helicopter. don't expect to find a nice neat closed form solution, unless you ignore aerodynamic effects completely. This is a real world engineering question, not theoretical physics!

Comment: Ask here https://engineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a lot of math here I would just provide you an analogy.

It is a somewhat similar situation(not identical) to the motion of a charged particle which makes an acute angle with an external uniform magnetic field but is parallel with a uniform external electric field.Due to the existence of a parallel component(parallel to magnetic field as well as electric field) of velocity,  the trajectory of the charged particle is of a **helix** with increasing pitch.

The situation of a fan is quite analogous to the case discussed above.It is not identical as a fan is a rigid body but the above case would be quite helpful to you if you want to derive the equation of trajectory of the whole fan by considering the trajectory of each and every particle of the fan.The magnetic field is just like the tension in the fan which provides centripetal force to every particle(except centre of fan) of the fan and gravitational field plays the role identical to that of electric field.

Hope the analogy helps you!